# Как подсчитать в массиве данные?

Tags: php

Есть массив.

```
$data=array('2020-03-02++User-yy' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-02++User1-vv' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-02++User2-cc' => 'V2A',
    '2020-03-02++User4-aa' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-03++User5-mm' => 'C5A',
    '2020-03-03++User6-nn' => 'V2A',
    '2020-03-03++User7-ii' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-03++User8-ff' => 'X5A',
    '2020-03-05++User9-tt' => 'X5A',
    '2020-03-05++User10-xx' => 'V2A',
    '2020-03-10++User11-zz' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-10++User12-dd' => 'LN-290',
    '2020-03-11++User13-gg' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-11++User14-ii' => 'X5A',
    '2020-03-11++User15-kk' => 'LN-430',
    '2020-03-23++User16-ss' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-24++User17-aa' => 'LN-430',
    '2020-03-24++User16-ss' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-25++User18-ee' => 'B728',
    '2020-03-25++User1-vv' => 'C0A',
    '2020-03-25++User19-ll' => 'LN-290',
    '2020-03-25++User20-pp' => 'V2A',
    '2020-03-25++User21-bb' => 'X5A',
    '2020-03-26++User22-kk' => 'X5A',
    '2020-03-26++User23-es' => 'C5A',
    '2020-03-27++User24-da' => 'C5A',
    '2020-03-27++User12-dd' => 'X5A',
    '2020-03-27++User25-ps' => 'C5A',
    '2020-03-30++User26-nn' => 'LN-290');
```

Задача состоит подсчитать Количество значений пример (COA-8 шт.)
Сложность в том что в ключе User1-vv несколько штук, но разброс в датах больше 10 дней значит считаем что за  User1-vv числится C0A-2 шт.
Если у User16-ss меньше 10 дней разброс то значение нужно посчитать как одно C0A-1 шт.
Ещё есть такая группа User12-dd у которых разные значения X5A и LN-290 их считаем по обычному
В итоге должно получиться

```
C0A-8 шт.
V2A-4 шт.
C5A-4 шт.
X5A-6 шт.
LN-290-3 шт.
LN-430-2 шт.
B728-1 шт.
```

Comment: Совершенно просто сгруппировать по коду а затем по юзерам, получите список дат. А вот как решать вопрос о близости (про 10 дней, это сложнее). Надо 10 дней от какой-то даты или между ними? а если будет несколько таких групп - самую большую выбирать, самую позднюю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно группировать по коду а затем по юзерам, а дальше посчитать, учитывая разницу минимальных и максимальных дат. Два цикла

```
$groups = [];
foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
    list($date, $user) = explode('++', $k);
    $groups[$v][$user][] = strtotime($date);
}
$sum = [];
foreach($groups as $c=>$u) {
    foreach($u as $x) {
        $min = min($x);
        $max = max($x);
        if (! isset($sum[$c])) $sum[$c] = 0;
        $sum[$c] += ($max-$min > 60*60*24*10) ? 2 : 1;
    }
}
print_r($sum);

 Array
(
    [C0A] => 8
    [V2A] => 4
    [C5A] => 4
    [X5A] => 6
    [LN-290] => 3
    [LN-430] => 2
    [B728] => 1
)
```